# Are there limited term identification cards in the UK?

Tags: uk, customs-and-immigration

I was reading about [Limited Term Identification Cards in the state of Texas](http://www.txdps.state.tx.us/DriverLicense/limitedTerm.htm) and was wondering...  does the UK have anything similar?

I'm just visiting for a week, so I don't think it's really that important, but I think ID cards, in general, are just cool souvenirs to have and plus I find the process of getting them to be interesting to see, first hand, too. I already have a drivers license for my state, a concealed handgun license, a passport card and a global entry card and am ready for more lol.

Comment: Big Brother isn't already watching you closely enough, eh?

Comment: What is the purpose of these limited term ID cards? Lawful non-national non-residents presumably all have a passport (or possibly a “refugee travel document”) and therefore do not actually need another form of ID.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing you are mis-understanding the definition of a "temporary visitor" in the sense that it is used on that website.

In order to receive a Drivers License or ID card in Texas, you must be a resident of the state, and must be able to prove that fact. The "Temporary" refers to the fact that you can be a resident of the state, but not a "permanent resident" - such as if you are in the country on a long-term work visa.

So yes, the UK does have something similar to what Texas has in that non-permanent residents can apply for an ID card/Drivers license - but no, you will not be able to receive one if you are visiting for a week.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot get any kind of UK ID card, as attempts to introduce ID cards in UK have been completely repelled by [Identity Documents Act 2010](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_Documents_Act_2010).

Comment: This law was mostly about ID cards for UK nationals however. Non-EU foreign national who live in the UK still can (and, in fact, must) get a biometric ID card/residence permit so it is perfectly possible to get an ID card in the UK. This does not exactly address the OP's question however as it is not available to non-residents, unlike the Texas thing.

Comment: @Annoyed: I was under impression that these were somehow related, and IDs for non-EU families of EU members were one of the pilots for general ID programme. Are residency cards still issued?